# Calling abstract method in superclass reference don't work

Tags: typescript

I have the following two classes:

```
export abstract class A{
   abstract document(): string;
}

export class B extends A{
   document(): string{
      return '0001';
   }
}
```

But when I do: `a: A = new B(); a.document();` I receive `a.document is not a function`

Why this happen?

Comment: it compiles for ts 3.3.333..., no warnings or errors, it runs on node  10.15.1...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Unless your build pipeline changes something after TypeScript compiles your code, there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Ok. The real problem is that I have a list of B in view. But when I pass a B instance to a A reference in my component class I got a `object` and not a B.

`<tr *ngFor="let b of listOfB">

                <td>{{b.something}}</td>

                <td >

                  <a (click)="del(b)" >

                  </a>

                </td>

              </tr>
`

In del funcion, when I print `console.log(typeof B);` I got a `object`